# Ubuntu 12.04 Installation on java for netbeans IDE 6.9.1

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am using ubuntu 12.04 on virtual machine but when i try to install java its gives me error like this

```
sudo apt-get sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-jre
[sudo] password for samkt: 
E: Invalid operation sun-java6-jdk
```

so now i am not able to install netbeans also because its required java and JVM for installing netbeans.

Comment: Also why not try Netbeans 7 with JDK 7?

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you forgot the "install" command.

```
sudo apt-get install <<type packages here>>
```

For example:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras chromium-browser python
```

And the full code for installing <strike>Gava</strike>Java:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

Look on this website: http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2012/01/sun-java-6-now-can-be-installed-on.html

It will explain everything from Java being removed from the Ubuntu repository to installing it via PPA.

**Install Sun Java 6 on Ubuntu via PPA
Of course, this news brings some panic to many Ubuntu users, but don't worry! You can still install Sun Java 6 via PPA:**

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:flexiondotorg/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin
```

**The above PPA contains Sun Java 6 package for Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx to Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin!**

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `install` command.

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-jre
```

I don't think this is going to solve your problem of installing this package, however, as I think it has been removed from the standard repositories per license requirements. You'll have to research a third-party location or install manually.

Answer (score 0):

i needed although the 6.9.1 Edition (for ruby support) [available here](http://netbeans.org/downloads/6.9.1/start.html?platform=linux&lang=en&option=ruby)
and i needed therefor the older java edition. So i went to the [oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jdk-6u34-oth-JPR) and searched for the older version (warning you need an oracle account). 
Execute the downloaded *.bin file 
and move the files to the ubuntu jvm dir

```
sudo mv jdk1.6.0_32 /usr/lib/jvm/
```

and enable jvm

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/javac 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/java 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/javaws 1
```

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
```

now check java version 
ready ;) 
i got the infos from [here](http://www.jusuchyne.com/codingforme/2012/05/installing-oracle-java-jdk-6-or-7-on-ubuntu-12-04/)