# while installing netbeans 6.9.1 on ubuntu 12.04 which is running on VM ware i am getting this error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, netbeans

while installing netbeans 6.9.1 on ubuntu 12.04  which is running on VM ware i am getting this error

```
sudo sh ./jdk-6u22-nb-6_9_1-linux-ml.sh 
[sudo] password for samkt: 
 Configuring the installer...
 Searching for JVM on the system...
   Preparing bundled JVM ...
./jdk-6u22-nb-6_9_1-linux-ml.sh: 1: eval: /tmp/.nbi-2064057.tmp/jre-6u20-linux-i586.bin: not found
Cannot extract bundled JVM
```

Comment: i think the answer can be found [here][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986588/ubuntu-12-04-installation-on-java-for-netbeans-ide-6-9-1/12891126#12891126

Answer (score 0):

Try install a latest JDK and restart OS

And Try your steps at again